# "=>" operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I mixed up *Ruby* with *JavaScript* syntax when trying to declare an associative array in *JavaScript*.

```
>>> [a => b, c => d]
```

This results in a valid array and

```
>>> JSON.stringify([a => b, c => d])
```

returns `"[null,null]"` and

```
typeof(a) === "undefined" // true
typeof(b) === "undefined" // true
typeof(c) === "undefined" // true
typeof(d) === "undefined" // true
```

What does this syntax mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the syntax for [ES6's arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions), which is both a shorthand and sets the values of `this` lexically. It uses the following syntax:

```
argument => returnValue
```

It can also be used with multiple arguments or with a function body (which makes a `return` statement needed for a non-void function):

```
() => 1
(arg1, arg2) => 2
argument => { return 3; }
```

The return value is implicit, which is why it appears to work. While this is still experimental, Firefox has implemented this, though other browsers have not yet done so.

The reason why you're getting `"[null]"` is that functions cannot be represented in JSON, so they are converted to `null` for serialisation purposes.

Comment: @Paniyar: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions

Comment: @Kos: not sure, but the main thing is about how the use of the `this` keyword can be misleading in some situations -- the behaviour of `this` is different in an arrow function, compared to normal functions. It's similar to what Coffeescript uses, as well as Ruby with its `->` operator.